# Retracing steps with emacs (When programming /exploring)

Tags: search, bookmarks, programming

Often when fixing a bug or implementing a new feature in a code repository, I start off with an investigatory step.

For example, I would have a lead, a word such as "Article" and I would start by grepping the codebase for "Article".
Suppose there are 5 files that contain the word. I would open up one of these files with emacs. Reading the file, I would learn that the code in that file is just a "wrapper" function, and the real meat of the work happens in another place (the parent/caller function)
This step would repeat for about a dozen times until I found what I'm looking for. Sometimes I don't find what I'm looking for.
Sometimes on a 10 step exploration ( 10 files opened up consecutively)
I would decide to take 4 steps back, and branch off in another direction/idea.

Four days later I would be in the shower and have a thought flash, and
would want to revisit/retrace my steps but the emacs instance has long
been killed.

Is bookmarks.el the answer? Or are there better ways to wander down
rabbit holes with emacs.

Comment: If you use `M-.` to jump to definitions, you can use `M-,` to go back to where you've looked for the definition. There's also the mark ring, which has the limitation to being separate for each buffer.

Comment: your answer was quite helpful, ,maybe you want to write it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Emacs bookmarks are a good answer for getting back to places later (and for restoring contexts later).

But that means that you need to create a bookmark, e.g., perhaps guessing that you might want to get back to the current place.

If you use [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) then you can optionally have Emacs [create bookmarks automatically](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#AutomaticBookmarking) whenever Emacs is idle for a given time period. You might or might not like to turn this on, e.g., when working on some code that you expect you might want to get back to.

---

Another part of your question mentions grepping for some code fragment. Another possibility is to try for a better grep search string: one that will avoid just "wrapper" code -- if that's possible.

Or you can maybe try using a different kind of search than just grep (which is line-oriented).
For instance, if you use library [`isearch-prop.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/isearch-prop.el) then you can 
search the zones of text that match a given regexp, using command `isearchp-regexp-context-search` or `isearchp-regexp-context-regexp-search`. In other words, don't use individual lines as search contexts; define the contexts to search as the text that matches a regexp.  (A similar feature is available with [Icicles search](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview).)

Comment: After reading https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus , Im very excited about trying it out in the coming days/weeks.   I wish the bookmarks list had a way to change the view when pressing backtrack,   so for example show tags, annots. as columns in the list. dired sometimes makes use of backtick like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use <kbd>M-.</kbd> to jump to definitions, and <kbd>M-,</kbd> to jump back to places you've looked from.

There's <kbd>M-?</kbd>, which can be used to find references in a project.

You can also use the mark ring to go back to places you've marked (for instance with <kbd>C-SPC</kbd>, or by using `isearch`) before, but this is limited to a buffer. You can pop the ring with <kbd>C-u C-SPC</kbd>. This can be handy, when you need to import something you're about to use before you get back to what you were writing as well.